# Two inequalities for holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ and let $z \in \mathbb{D}$. I have to prove that
$$
\frac{|f(0)| - |z|}{1 + |f(0)| |z|} \leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{|f(0)| + |z|}{1 - |f(0)| |z|}
$$
and I have thought to use Schwarz-Pick theorem but I haven't obtain any result. Any help? Thank you very much.